# Java generic operation result type

Tags: java, templates, generics, types

I'm not professional Java programmer, so this question could be simple, but I have searched the web for the answer but found nothing so far.

Lets say we have a generic class in Java:

```
public class C1 <T, U> {
  public /*TYPE*/ f(T t, U u) {  
    return t.g(u)
  }
```

The question is - how can I determine the type of the result of this generic example?
Is it somehow possible to write something like `typeof(t.g(u))`?

Comment: g is a method of instance t of class T, that accepts 1 argument of type U and returns result of type X.

Comment: As it stands, you can't even call `t.g()` since `T` has no upper bound. `T` is not a class, it is a type parameter.

Comment: @danilo2  Is X a specific type, or itself generic? How, it at all, does it relate to T and U?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call `t.g(u)` as is because `T` is an unbounded type. You need to put a compile-time bound on it so the compiler knows what methods are available. Otherwise you'll only be able to call `Object` methods since the only thing the compiler can infer about `T` is that is extends `Object`.

For example, if you have an interface `G<U>` with the `g` method you want to call:

```
public interface G<U> {
    R g(U u);
}
```

Then you would specify that `T extends G<U>`, which lets you call `g()`. And now you know what the return type of `g()` is: it's `R`.

```
public class C1<T extends G<U>, U> {
    public R f(T t, U u) {  
        return t.g(u)
    }
}
```

If you want the result of `g()` to be dependent on types `T` and `U` then you could do something like this:

```
public interface G<T, U> {
    T g(U u);
}

public class C1<T, U> {
    public T f(G<T, U> g, U u) {  
        return g.g(u)
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful - you're alternatively treating `U` as a concrete type and a type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't going to compile as is because there's nothing to tell the compiler that `t` has a member function `g`. You would need to declare the type parameter `T` as extending some base class or interface that did, indeed, declare a `g()` method. The return type would be the return type of `g` (which may be another parametric type).

For example:

```
public interface Foo<X, Y> {
    X g(Y u);
}

public class C1 <T extends Foo<X, U>, U, X> {
    public X f(T t, U u) {  
        return t.g(u);
    }
}
```

Note that if the return type `X` is also generic, you need to declare a separate type parameter for it in class `C1`. Alternatively, you could declare `C1` to deal uniformly with a single parameterized type (e.g., `String` × `String` → `String`):

```
public class C1 <T extends Foo<T, T>> {
    public T f(T t, T u) {  
        return t.g(u);
    }
}
```

Other variations are also possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce t to have the method g, you must declare your class like this:

```
public class C1<T extends Ginterface, U extends SecInterface> {
}
```

and the return type of this method will be the return type of g function in Ginterface